# Passing a parameter to a subquery as a fieldname in MS Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm looking to (in Access SQL not VBA) pass a parameter based on a field value of a parent query.  Any idea's?

```
SELECT 
o25Year, 
(SELECT 'Y' & [p0] FROM tblOCA WHERE LEID = tblo25U.LEID) AS OCI
FROM tblo25U
```

What I'd like to do is pull the data from a field named Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4 or Y5 respectivly depending on the value of o25Year.  Is this possible in SQL or am I stuck converting a nice fast query into sluggish VBA?  Basically set parameter p0 = o25Year and then pull the data from the Y*o25Year* field.

Redesigning the table into a more useful structure on either end is not an option.

Comment: That is not possible. How do you feel about changing the sql string of the query using vba? In that case, you could write the sql to suit, so a mixture of VBA and SQL.

Comment: @Remou I was hoping to avoid it if I could, if it's not possible here I'll whip up a quick function to accept the year and LEID and spit out my value. Just slows things down a bit usually.  Thanks for letting me know.